# Do not display zeros after decimal point in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm trying to remove the trailing zeros, after the decimal point, from the first row of the following matrix `A`.

```
A1 = [130: -20: 10]
A2 = [1: 11/6: 12]
A3 = [1/2: 1/4: 2]*pi

A = [A1; A2; A3]
```

Which is displayed as:

```
A = 130.0000  110.0000   90.0000   70.0000   50.0000   30.0000   10.0000
      1.0000    2.8333    4.6667    6.5000    8.3333   10.1667   12.0000
      1.5708    2.3562    3.1416    3.9270    4.7124    5.4978    6.2832
```

The final matrix has to be like this one:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: You mean you don't want the trailing zeros?

Comment: But... the first row has no decimals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
A1 = [130: -20: 10];
A2 = [1: 11/6: 12];
A3 = [1/2: 1/4: 2]*pi;
format shortG % Where the magic happens
A = [A1; A2; A3]
A =

          130          110           90           70           50           30           10
            1       2.8333       4.6667          6.5       8.3333       10.167           12
       1.5708       2.3562       3.1416        3.927       4.7124       5.4978       6.2832
```

Just use `format shortG`. The zeros are there technically only as a numerical accuracy-thing. Check the [documentation on `format`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html) for all display styles.