# How can i get 6 digits after comma (matlab)?

Tags: matlab, rounding, precision

I read from text some comma seperated values.

- -8.618643,41.141412
- -8.639847,41.159826
- ...

I write script below;

```
get_in = zeros(lendata,2);
nums = str2num(line); % auto comma seperation.(two points)
for x=1:2
get_in(i,x)=nums(x);
end
```

it automatically round numbers. For example;

> (first row convert to "-8.6186 , 41.1414")

How can i ignore round operation?

I want to get 6 digits after comma.

I tried "str2double" after split line with comma delimeter.

I tried import data tool

But it always rounded to 4 digits, too.

Comment: Only the _displayed_ values are rounded. The actual variables have better precision (about 15 significant figures). Use `format long` to check

Comment: Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42483474/5211833), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32524236/5211833).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As one of the replies has already said, the values aren't actually rounded, just the displayed values (for ease of reading them).  As suggested, if you just enter 'format long' into the command window that should help.

The following link might help with displaying individual values to certain decimal places though: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/118222

It suggests using the `sprintf` function.  For example `sprintf(%4.6,data)` would display the value of 'data' to 6 decimal places.